# Sticky footer in an email with a download button

Tags: html, css, linkedin-api, html-email

Some days ago I received an e-mail from LinkedIn which offers a new LinkedIn app (LinkedIn Job Search). I was surprised by the footer bar which was sticking to the bottom of the screen.

I'm very curious how to build this! Google didn't help me any further and I didn't see it before. Can anyone help me further?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you have checked from the e-mail source code how they did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `position: fixed;` and many mobile clients that support media queries. `position: fixed;` becomes more [problematic on desktop and web clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), but if we wrap the behavior in a media query it works well:

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .fixed {
        position: fixed;
        bottom:0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed">
    <A href="#">LinkedIn Ad</a>
</div>
```

**Note:** this will not work in mobile clients that do no support media queries (like Gmail).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do this was to use flexbox using:

```
body
    height: 100%
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column

.container
    flex: 1

.footer
    position: relative
    bottom: 0px
    height: 50px
    flex-shrink: 0
```

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/RPAraujo/pen/GqPyBp/

It works in modern browsers not sure how it will work inside an email App

Comment: [Flexbox is not well supported in email clients](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/1500-using-flexbox-in-an-email), so it's not a great idea to use it for primary layout.